# How to run PHP's build in server in the background

Tags: php

I upgraded to PHP 5.5, and I can't run the server in the background anymore.

```
ablock@desktop:~/site$ php -S localhost:3000 -t public/ &
[1] 9689
ablock@desktop:~/site$ 

[1]+  Stopped                 php -S localhost:3000 -t public/
ablock@desktop:~/site$
```

As you can see, the server stops right away.

Comment: What happens if you run it under [strace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace)?

Comment: Does that mean `strace php -S localhost:3000 -t public/ &`?

Comment: Yes, you can also try to run PHP under gdb. Also see http://derickrethans.nl/what-is-php-doing.html

Comment: When I run with strace it just runs...it appears to be waiting for something to happen, but I don't see anything that looks like a crash.

Comment: I just tested this out. It looks like the build in web server terminates if it can not read/write stdout. Redirecting stdout to null seem to work. Try `php -S localhost:3000 -t public/ 1>/dev/null &`.

Comment: Can you write that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a process is set to run in the background (using the `&` operator) it can no longer write to the terminal. A `SIGTTOU` signal is generated and it's default action is to terminate the process since it no longer is able to write to `stdout`.

By redirecting `stdout` somewhere writable we can make sure that there will be no `SIGTTOU` signal and thous no termination of the process.

```
php -S localhost:3000 -t public/ 1>/dev/null &
```

`1>` means `stdout`, while `2>` means `stderr`, used for errors. Both can be redirected to a file or a pseudo-devices using `&>`.